# Ansible: merge elements of stdout_results dict items in loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I try to maintain templates for nginx configuration file snippets. These snippets I want to apply to different types of webservers, where each server only needs a subset of these snippets.
My approach (maybe theres a better one) was to create subdirs per host_group (e.g.proxy-nodes) and link the required files, so I only need to maintain templates in one place.
My templates folder looks like this:

```
    nginx.conf
    proxy-nodes
    ├── conf.d
    └── snippets
        ├── cors.conf -> ../../snippets/cors.conf
        ├── proxy_backend.conf -> ../../snippets/proxy_backend.conf
        ├── proxy_conditions.conf -> ../../snippets/proxy_conditions.conf
        ├── proxy_location_assets.conf -> ../../snippets/proxy_location_assets.conf
        ├── proxy_static_params.conf -> ../../snippets/proxy_static_params.conf
        └── ssl.conf -> ../../snippets/ssl.conf
    snippets
    ├── backend.conf
    ├── ban.conf
    ├── cors.conf
    ├── proxy_backend.conf
    ├── proxy_conditions.conf
    ├── proxy_location_assets.conf
    ├── proxy_static_params.conf
    └── ssl.conf
```

Then I try to extract a list of files I need to template out to the host:

```
- name: create dict of group dirs with snippets files                                               
  shell: ls roles/nginx/templates/{{ item|quote }}/snippets/* | cut -d'/' -f4-
  register: nginx_group_dirs 
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_lines: for i in $(ls -d roles/nginx/templates/*/); do echo $i | cut -f4 -d'/'; done
  when: item in group_names
```

This gives me multiple items with files in nginx_group_dirs.results.item.stdout_lines:

```
"nginx_group_dirs": {
    "changed": true, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
 ...
            },
            "item": "proxy-nodes", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2018-09-12 10:45:14.652846", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "proxy-nodes/snippets/backend.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/ban.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/cors.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_backend.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_conditions.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_location_assets.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_static_params.conf\nproxy-nodes/snippets/ssl.conf", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "proxy-nodes/snippets/cors.conf", 
                "proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_backend.conf", 
                "proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_conditions.conf", 
                "proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_location_assets.conf", 
                "proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_static_params.conf", 
                "proxy-nodes/snippets/ssl.conf"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
            "_ansible_item_label": "snippets", 
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "changed": false, 
            "item": "snippets", 
            "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", 
            "skipped": true
        },
```

Later I realized, that while listing the directory structure only for matching group_names leads to some items having no stdout_lines.
My problem now is to find the proper loop and/or filter syntax to template out all relevant stdout_lines files of multiple items.

```
- name: template snippets for all applicable groups
  template: 
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/etc/nginx/snippets/{{ item | basename }}"
    backup: yes
    with_items: "{{ nginx_group_dirs.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
    when: item.stdout_lines is defined
```

I added the when: clause which gives  me this output (here are more items, becase I did'nt want to expand the post:

```
TASK [nginx : template snippets for all applicable groups] ********************************************
skipping: [eu-proxy1] => (item=[Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, [u'eu-proxy-nodes/sites-available/default'], [u'proxy-nodes/snippets/cors.conf', u'proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_backend.conf', u'proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_conditions.conf', u'proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_location_assets.conf', u'proxy-nodes/snippets/proxy_static_params.conf', u'proxy-nodes/snippets/ssl.conf'], Undefined, Undefined])
```

If I use techrafs suggestion without when clause

```
with_items: "{{ nginx_group_dirs.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | flattened }}"
```

I get (because some items have no 'stdout_lines' ?):

```
fatal: [eu-proxy1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"}
```

So I guess I additionally need to get rid of the undefined items somehow. Any ideas ?

Comment: @techraf: thanks for the quick resonse, I tried this, but realized, that my example misses some details I was not aware of, I will update my post...mainly that there are more items in the templates directory, which have stdout_results "undefined", because they are not in any matching group_names.

Answer (score 1):

Your template:

```
{{ nginx_group_dirs.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}
```

produces a list of lists (`stdout_lines`).

As you want to iterate over the elements of all `stdout_lines`, you need to flatten your result:

```
{{ nginx_group_dirs.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | flatten }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get the templating running, but seems a bit odd to me:

```
- name: create dict of group dirs with subdirs and files
  shell: ls -d1 roles/nginx/templates/{{ item|quote }}/*/* | cut -d'/' -f4- 
  register: nginx_group_dirs
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_lines: for i in $(ls -d roles/nginx/templates/*/); do echo $i | cut -f4 -d'/'; done
  when: item in group_names

- debug: msg="{{ item.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"
  register: file_list
  loop: "{{ nginx_group_dirs.results }}"

- name: template snippets for all applicable groups
  template: 
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/etc/nginx/{{ item | regex_replace('^(\\w(-?))+\\/', '') }}"
    backup: yes
  loop: "{{ file_list.results | map(attribute='msg') | flatten }}"
```